# Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : cannot use this function

Tags: raster, r

I am doing Mann-kendall test in R using follow code but unexpectedly facing an error

```
setwd("F:/.../rasters/")
getwd()

rlist = lapply(1:111, function(i){raster(matrix(runif(20),5,4))})

rasters=stack(rlist)
rasters
fun_kendall <- function(x){ return(unlist(MannKendall(x)))}
kendall_result <- calc(rasters,fun_kendall)
```

and error is

```
Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : cannot use this function
```

If anyone knows why it is giving this error and how to get rid off this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load the package which provides the function `MannKendal()`.

In your case just add

```
library(Kendall)
```

If you an error like this

> `Error in library(Kendall) : there is no package called ‘Kendall’`

just install the package using

```
install.packages('Kendall')
```